# Return all Tags and Categories in Separate List

Tags: categories, shortcode, search, tags, list

I am using the snippet below to create a shortcode to get all tags for a search in a separate list including tag count. Eg search for 'foo' and it returns all tags for all posts that match the search 'foo'.

I am trying to also get the categories from the same search in a separate list using a second shortcode from the same global search. I am not sure how I can get the categories from the same global search.

Eg search for for 'foo' and get:

Tag: Tag1 (10), Tag2 (20), Tag3 (2) etc (this is the shortcode and already works)

Category: Cat1 (10), Cat2 (2) etc. (not sure how to get the second shortcode to work)

```
    function get_query_terms_list( $taxonomy = 'post_tag', $sep = '' ) {
    $list = array();

    foreach ( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->posts as $post ) {
        if ( is_array( $terms = get_the_terms( $post, $taxonomy ) ) ) {
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                // Set the term's initial count.
                if ( ! isset( $list[ $term->term_id ] ) ) {
                    $list[ $term->term_id ] = 0;
                }
                // And then increment it for each post.
                $list[ $term->term_id ]++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Sort by the count, highest to lowest.
    arsort( $list );

    $links = array();

    foreach ( $list as $term_id => $count ) {
        $term = get_term( $term_id );
        $link = get_term_link( $term );

        if ( ! is_wp_error( $link ) ) {
            $links[] = '<a style="background-color:#fffff; border-radius:20px; box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 8%); font-weight: bold; color:#6c757d; padding:8px; margin:5px;" href="'.$link.'">' . __( $term->name ) ." ($count)". '</a>'.'';
            
        }
    }

    return '<div style="height:50px; padding-top:10px; overflow-x:auto; white-space: nowrap;">'.implode( $sep, $links ).'</div>';
}
```

Shortcode

```
add_shortcode( 'bd_terms_list', 'bd_terms_list_custom_callback');
function bd_terms_list_custom_callback( $args ){
    return get_query_terms_list( 'gd_place_tags' );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how I can get the categories from the same global search

You can add a `taxonomy` attribute to your shortcode and then pass the value to `get_query_terms_list()`, like so:

```php
add_shortcode( 'bd_terms_list', 'bd_terms_list_custom_callback');
function bd_terms_list_custom_callback( $args ){
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array( // list of default attributes
        'taxonomy' => 'gd_place_tags',
        'sep'      => '', // optional, but you might use it someday? :)
    ), $args );

    return get_query_terms_list( $atts['taxonomy'], $atts['sep'] );
}
```

See the [Shortcodes API on Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Handling_Attributes) for more details about handling shortcode attributes.

And for example with the default `post_tag` and `category` taxonomies included in WordPress core, you can display the tags and categories in separate list like so:

```html
Tags: [bd_terms_list taxonomy="post_tag"]

Categories: [bd_terms_list taxonomy="category"]
```

So you really just need to use the correct **taxonomy** *slug*, just like you could see above.

**In response to your comment:**

> the slug for category is 'gd_postcategory' without the underscore for
> some reason. I'm not sure how to fix the underscore, so I added 2 x
> shortcodes now instead of using the more elegant taxonomy="category".
> It works :)

Why would you need to "fix the underscore"?

And you do know the differences between taxonomies and terms, don't you? (see https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/categories-tags-custom-taxonomies/)

So for example, if I registered custom "tag" and "category" taxonomies named `gd_place_tags` and `gd_postcategory` respectively, then I would display the tag/category list like so:

```html
Tags: [bd_terms_list taxonomy="gd_place_tags"]

Categories: [bd_terms_list taxonomy="gd_postcategory"]
```

But if you're absolutely *certain* the above just doesn't work for you, then yes of course, you could just create another shortcode which calls the `get_query_terms_list()` function. :)

However, if I were you, I would try again with the modified `bd_terms_list_custom_callback()` function as well as the HTML code above, but I would double-check that I'm using the correct ***taxonomy slugs*** (and not the label like "My Taxonomy" or even the slug of a *term* in the taxonomy like `my-category-in-my-taxonomy`).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the prompt reply :) This makes sense to me but I can't get it to work. I added the above snippet to the functions.php  and used the shortcode but I can't get it to work. How does the shortcode get the 'catgeories' or 'tags'? Sorry, this might be a super obvious thing that I am missing.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to correct the taxonomy. So the default `taxonomy` value in the shortcode is `gd_place_tags` and therefore you could simply do `[bd_terms_list]`. But for other taxonomies, you need to use the `taxonomy` attribute like so: `[bd_terms_list taxonomy="my_taxonomy"]`. So just replace the `my_taxonomy` with the correct taxonomy slug, like `gd_place_categories`, maybe?

Comment: Thank you :) I found the issue after reading your last post. the slug for category is 'gd_postcategory' without the underscore for some reason. I'm not sure how to fix the underscore, so I added 2 x shortcodes now instead of using the more elegant taxonomy="category". It works :) Thank you so much for your reply. This is the second time you actually assist me with this. Thank you :)

Comment: I've added that to my answer and I'd appreciate if you can accept it? Or at least read it carefully and let me know what you think? :)

Comment: I missed that :) Thank you. That fixed the issue and I don't need to create a second shortcode. Thank you again for following this up and updating the last post. This made it very clear. Very silly I missed this :)